subring generated by an invertible element
Let $R$ be a unital ring and $a\in R$ an invertible element and $a\neq 1$. Let $S_a:=\langle 1,a\rangle\subset R$ be the unital subring generated by $a$. That is, the smallest unital subring containing $a$. Can I conclude $a^{-1}\in S_a$ iff $a^{-1}=p(a)$ for some polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$? That is, is it possible to have $a^{-1}\notin S_a$?
I'm asking since every division ring $D$ is not only simple but also one-sided simple. But if an element of $D$ generates a proper subring without its inverse, then that subring wouldn't be one-sided simple anymore, because it contains a noninvertible element. It seems anti-intuitive to me this possibility could happen somehow. Thanks inadvance.

Take the example $\Bbb Z = \langle 1, 2\rangle\subseteq \Bbb Q$, and note that $\frac12\notin \Bbb Z$.
Indeed, we do have $S_a = \{p(a)\mid p\in \Bbb Z[x]\}$. Clearly, every (integer coefficient) polynomial evaluated at $a$ must be in $S_a$. On the other hand, this set of polynomials contains $1$ and is closed under every ring operation, so it is a unital subring of $R$, and must therefore contain $S_a$. Therefore they must be equal.
